# What does "dop" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I happened to  come across the following sentences in a textbook story:

> "A flame goes up dop in all Nomita's nerves and veins".

In the same story, the word is repeated somewhere else later in the following sentence:

> "The flame that had gone up dop now burns steadily, hissing, sounding 
>   its note on each of her mind's strings".

What does the word *dop* mean in these sentences?

Comment: Please could you add a reference as well as any research you've already done? It's not a word I've heard of before and looking up the definitions, non of them seem to fit!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a non-English word.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, how did you know that my question was about a non-English word? I hadn't known it before got an answer here. I believed *dop* was an English word. It's pity you people are still enjoying down voting to close the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This website](https://www.parabaas.com/translation/database/translations/stories/ashapurna_matchbox.html) shows that it is a translation from Bengali.

It has 'dop' in italics with an exclamation mark - *dop!*. This is meant to be the sound effect of a sudden flame. Read this as 'A flame goes up (sound effect) in all Nomita's nerves and veins' and 'The flame that had gone up (sound effect) now burns steadily, hissing, sounding its note on each of her mind's strings'.

Comment: Excellent finding., Thank you! But in the textbook, there is no such punctuations. The story is a translation from Bengali.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a picture of the source...

> [image]

...from which it should be obvious that italicised ***dop!*** is an onomatopoeic form (not a standard one, just a creative "one-off" coinage for the context). It's supposed to represent the sound of a flame igniting, where more common alternatives include ***Pop!, Poof!, Whoosh!*** (normally capitalised in such contexts).